# Campo ler tags HTML no JSF

Tags: java, html, jsf

Gostaria de no meu campo que irei adicionar o texto e enviar para o banco, adicionar por exemplo um link ex: `<a href="http://www.globo.com/" ></a>`, porém, ao imprimir na tela, vinda do banco, ele imprimi a tag completa, não convertendo em link. Como poderia fazer?

Comment: em qual tag você está exibindo o resultado do banco?

Comment: estás usando PrimeFaces?

Comment: Sim estou usando PrimeFaces

Comment: @Alisson em qual tag está tentando colocar o reultado?

Comment: Já consegui resolver usando o escape em um campo outputText. Ex: <h:outputText value="#{beanMB.cliente.descricao}" escape="false"/>. Correto né?

Comment: @Alisson, publica o código  como resposta. Já tive o mesmo problema.

Comment: poisé ia dizer @Alisson hehe, então só comenta como resposta, vai ajudar outras pessoas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando o *escape* em um campo `h:outputText`.

Ex: `<h:outputText value="#{beanMB.cliente.descricao}" escape="false"/>`

Também funciona com o `p:outpuLabel`

Ex: `<p:outputLabel value="#{beanMB.cliente.descricao}" escape="false" />`